# Getting the nth week Monday of array of dates

Tags: php

I have an array of dates.  Some of the Mondays of these dates may be missing due to bank holiday or other, so instead i would get the next available date to represent that week.

```
$array = array("May 30 2017","May 29 2017","May 28 2017","May 26 2017","May 25 2017","May 24 2017","May 23 2017","May 19 2017","May 18 2017","May 17 2017","May 16 2017","May 15 2017","May 12 2017","May 11 2017","May 10 2017","May 09 2017","May 08 2017","May 05 2017","May 04 2017","May 03 2017","May 02 2017","May 01 2017","Apr 28 2017","Apr 27 2017","Apr 26 2017","Apr 25 2017","Apr 24 2017","Apr 21 2017","Apr 20 2017","Apr 19 2017","Apr 18 2017","Apr 17 2017","Apr 14 2017","Apr 13 2017","Apr 12 2017","Apr 11 2017","Apr 10 2017","Apr 07 2017","Apr 06 2017","Apr 05 2017","Apr 04 2017","Apr 03 2017","Mar 31 2017","Mar 30 2017","Mar 29 2017");
```

I eventually want to do this for 2 weeks, 3 weeks etc so i've added the parameter `w`

```
if(isset($_GET['w'])) {
        $week_loop = $_GET['w']*5;
}


if(isset($_GET['w'])) {
 foreach($array as $date) {
    $array_date = date("D",strtotime($date));


        if($array_date=="Mon") {
                echo "<p>Mon - ".date("j/m/y",strtotime($date))." - count($i)</p>";
                $i = 0;
        } 


     }

     $i++;

}
```

I'm having the problem progressing, so far i only display all Mondays in the array.  How do i incorporate every 2 weeks, 3 weeks etc into the loop and get the first available Date from that week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution is commented for explanation:

```
<?php

$array = array("May 30 2017","May 29 2017","May 28 2017","May 26 2017","May 25 2017","May 24 2017","May 23 2017","May 19 2017","May 18 2017","May 17 2017","May 16 2017","May 15 2017","May 12 2017","May 11 2017","May 10 2017","May 09 2017","May 08 2017","May 05 2017","May 04 2017","May 03 2017","May 02 2017","May 01 2017","Apr 28 2017","Apr 27 2017","Apr 26 2017","Apr 25 2017","Apr 24 2017","Apr 21 2017","Apr 20 2017","Apr 19 2017","Apr 18 2017","Apr 17 2017","Apr 14 2017","Apr 13 2017","Apr 12 2017","Apr 11 2017","Apr 10 2017","Apr 07 2017","Apr 06 2017","Apr 05 2017","Apr 04 2017","Apr 03 2017","Mar 31 2017","Mar 30 2017","Mar 29 2017");

// convert these to DateTime objects
$array = array_map(function($date){
    return new DateTime($date);
}, $array);

// sort them chronologically
sort($array);

// chunk array into weeks
foreach ($array as $date) {
    $weeks[$date->format("W")] []= $date;
}

// optional filter by week group (e.g. ?w=2 or ?w=3)
if (isset($_GET['w'])) {
    $week_loop = $_GET['w'];
} else {
    $week_loop = 1;
}

// echo first day of each week
$count = 1;
foreach ($weeks as $number => $week) {
    if ($week_loop - $count === 0) {
        echo "<p>week: $number - {$week[0]->format("D")} - {$week[0]->format("j/m/y")}</p>\n";
        $count = 1;
    } else {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

without arguments, prints every week:

> week: 13 - Wed - 29/03/17
>
> week: 14 - Mon - 3/04/17
>
> week: 15 - Mon - 10/04/17
>
> week: 16 - Mon - 17/04/17
>
> week: 17 - Mon - 24/04/17
>
> week: 18 - Mon - 1/05/17
>
> week: 19 - Mon - 8/05/17
>
> week: 20 - Mon - 15/05/17
>
> week: 21 - Tue - 23/05/17
>
> week: 22 - Mon - 29/05/17

given `?w=2`

> week: 14 - Mon - 3/04/17
>
> week: 16 - Mon - 17/04/17
>
> week: 18 - Mon - 1/05/17
>
> week: 20 - Mon - 15/05/17
>
> week: 22 - Mon - 29/05/17

given `?w=3`

> week: 15 - Mon - 10/04/17
>
> week: 18 - Mon - 1/05/17
>
> week: 21 - Tue - 23/05/17